# Update hasone relation behaves strangely (cakephp)

Tags: cakephp, relationship

I've got an existing Showcase that `hasOne` Gallery.
The Gallery already exists with the foreignKey `showcase_id` set to the proper value.
The Gallery has a text field that I try to update via the Showcase-controller.
The result I get is an extra Gallery entry, along the original one, instead of an update of the original entry.

What am I doing wrong?

My Showcase-view looks as follows:

> `echo $form->create('Showcase', array('action'=>'update'));`
>
> `echo $form->input('Showcase.id', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>$showcase['Showcase']['id']));`
>
> `echo $form->input('Gallery.fulltext', array('type'=>'textarea', 'between'=>'<br>', 'value'=>$showcase['Gallery']['fulltext']));`
>
> `echo $form->submit('Submit text');`
>
> `echo $form->end();`

My Showcase-controller function:

> `$uses = array('Showcase','Gallery')`
>
> `function update(){`
>
> `if(!empty($this->data)){`
>
> `$this->Showcase->saveAll($this->data, array('validate'=>'first'));`
>
> `}`
>
> `}`

The Showcase model `$hasOne = 'Gallery'` and the Gallery model `$belongsTo = 'Showcase'`.

Is `$this->Showcase->saveAll()` the proper function to use here? Or do I maybe need to update the Gallery entry within the Gallery controller? That will probably work but is seems so un-elegant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see what you mean by being un-elegant, it would be nice if it realised you had a hasOne relationship and therefore updated any existing record.

However currently within the framework I think your best option would be to add `echo $form->input('Gallery.id', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>$showcase['Gallery']['id']));` to your view.

As a side note. In the controller action that is currently defining `$showcase` if you instead assign it to `$this->data` then you won't need to always specify `'value' => ...` in your form inputs.