# Saving corresponding data in a hasOne relation

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

As I read in other postings, the id of the table, which has a relation to the frist model has to be set by an hidden field in the form.

```
echo $form->input('Gallery.id', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>$showcase['Gallery']['id']));
```

(see question at [Update hasone relation behaves strangely (cakephp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037352/update-hasone-relation-behaves-strangely-cakephp))

But isn't that risky, because anyone could edit this hidden field value and another dataset would be updated.

What is the best option to avoid such security issues when trying to update a whole dataset with 2 models associated together with a hasOne / belongsTo relation?

Thx

Best
Stefan

Comment: agreed, that's risky. You could cypher it ?

Comment: what could be done is to read the data of the first model and set the id for the second one:

    $userdata = $this -> User -> read(null, $id);
    $this -> request -> data['Usersetting']['id'] = $userdata['Usersetting']['id'];

But thats one more db query.

Answer (score 0):

1st option is to have multiple queries and checks on save

2nd option is http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#form-tampering-prevention

So whatever method works best in your particular case...

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to using UUIDs. Just need to change your primary key and foreign key to char(36) and cake will do the rest.